# Where does jquery UI Autocomplete store the ui.conent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

When the menu is open I would like to access the ui.content array but I can't find it in the object anywhere.

I can find the menu with this code but that doesn't have all the elements that are passed to the ui.content.

```
$(selector).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.element[0]
```

Any suggestions.  What i'd like to do is add items to the menu after the menu has opened.

**EDIT**

My question is where is the equivalent of ui.content stored when the menu is open?

Answer (score 1):

From the JQuery UI doc:

`response( event, ui )` Type: autocompleteresponse

Triggered after a search completes, before the menu is shown. Useful for local manipulation of suggestion data, where a custom source option callback is not required. This event is always triggered when a search completes, even if the menu will not be shown because there are no results or the Autocomplete is disabled.

`event` Type: Event

`ui` Type: Object

`ui.content` Type: Array

Contains the response data and can be modified to change the results that will be shown. This data is already normalized, so if you modify the data, make sure to include both value and label properties for each item.
Code examples:
Initialize the autocomplete with the response callback specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  response: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Bind an event listener to the autocompleteresponse event:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "autocompleteresponse", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

So you can get hold of `ui.content` in the call back handlers.
Have a look at [JQuery UI autocomplete API](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Comment: This is provides access to the ui.content before the menu opens but I would like to access the content after the menu is open.

Comment: I'm not sure y u need it when menu is open. But in that case u can then try using other api's `focus( event, ui )`. The doc says that `ui` is empty for `òpen` callback

Comment: I updated my question: I am trying to figure out where the equivalent of ui.content stored when the menu is open.

Comment: @NiranjanBorawake thanks bud! This is what I was looking for!